# Dumping sqlite3 database for use in Titanium

Tags: database, sqlite, titanium

So, for some reason, I am having a bit of trouble with my sqlite database. I'm trying to dump my database into a file that could be used in Titanium. I know about the `.dump` command, but when I try to use the instructions on the sqlite website:

> A good way to make an archival copy of a database is this:
>
> `$ echo '.dump' | sqlite3 ex1 | gzip -c >ex1.dump.gz`

and change the `ex1.dump.gz` to `ex1.sqlite.gz`, it gives a really messed up file that is useless. How can I dump my database so that I can then use it in my Titanium Studios mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you dump the database file when you can simply copy it, i.e. use it as it is?

As explained [here](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html), sqlite databases are cross-platform:

> A database in SQLite is a single disk file. Furthermore, the file
>   format is cross-platform. A database that is created on one machine
>   can be copied and used on a different machine with a different
>   architecture. SQLite databases are portable across 32-bit and 64-bit
>   machines and between big-endian and little-endian architectures.

On the other hand, you should be able to dump, compress you database like this:

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 foo.db | gzip -c > foo.dump.gz
```

and restore it in a new SQLite database:

```
gunzip -c foo.dump.gz | sqlite3 foo.new.db
```

Answer (score 1):

`.dump` exports the contents of your database as a series of insert statements.  If you run it without the `gzip` command you'll see plain text sql:

```
$ echo '.dump' | sqlite3 ex1
```

But you don't need to do that to use a SQLite database in Titanium Studios.  It supports SQLite natively.  Just copy the database file to your project directory and then use code like this to open it:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('../products.sqlite','products');  

var rows = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products');
```

More details here:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite/

Comment: Both of the answers said the same thing, but you included a bit more relevance. What I did was I just copied the file I was using in sqlite3 and then moved it over to the resources folder in my app. Though I was just wondering, is there any difference between `select distict category` vs `select category`? Which should I use?

Comment: @undacovabroda45, `select distinct` will filter out duplicates, `select` by itself will include all results, even duplicates.

Comment: @undacovabroda45: I guess I'm a bit of a sore loser, but how is my answer less relevant as I made it a general point, not a Titanium thingie point, that sqlite files are cross-platform. Furthermore, the answer you selected makes the same two point I made _after_, albeit with more details on using .dump, but once again with less details on the portability of sqlite.

Comment: Yes I know. Both of your answers were certainly correct. At the end of the day, there were really no differences between your answers. I did see your answer first, so I'll restore credit where credit is due.